# Can you do a for loop with underscore.js?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to generate a select tag with multiple options using underscore.js. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
            <% for(i=1; i++; i <= 20) { %>
                <option value="<%= i %>"><%= i %>km</option>
            <% } %>
```

Because this does not work. Everything is in a script template tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
<% for(i=1; i++; i <= 20) { %>
```

is wrong. Change it to

```
<% for(i=1; i <= 20; i++) { %>
```